# Windows 7 Standy/Hibernate Freeze/Lockup

Tags: windows-7, windows, freeze, hibernate, standby

I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on a MSI U100 Netbook which often experiences a lockup or freeze whilst hibernating or shutting down.

I have a friend with an Asus netbook running Windows 7 who has experienced the same issue. This happens to me perhaps 1-2 times a week, and is frustrating  because it will just sit there running flat out (the fan goes to max after a while) until the battery dies if I don't notice it first.

Just wondering if anyone has had any similar issues or might be able to point me in the right direction.

The freeze occurs when the screen has faded to black. The HDD light flickers for a few moments then just sticks on solid. I haven't been able to isolate any apps which may be causing this either. It will be fine one standby, and lock up the next with no new apps open.

Any thoughts greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Kyle

Answer (score 0):

The event log may indicate what is going on. You should also try running a hardware diagnostic package, starting with the one provided with the computer.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, feel free to upvote the answer.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the rep on this site yet

Answer (score 0):

I am told that having drive encryption can cause flakiness in the hibernation system.  We have SSD drives and drive encryption.  Our IT support people simply remove hibernation from the system dialogue, saying, "Don't use hibernation, it doesn't work reliably with these T420s in Windows 7".

Comment: Thanks, good thought but no dice. This laptop wasn't using any kind of encryption.